# I want to print even and odd number from an input array list

Tags: java

I want to print even and odd number from an input array list.

Input : 1 2 3 4

Expected output

Even number is : 2 4

Odd number is : 1 3

but i get my output is

```
Odd number is [1]
Even number is [2]
Odd number is [1, 3]
Even number is [2, 4]
```

I think is the for loop there might put wrongly?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int[]number=new int[10];
        Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number :" );

        for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++){
            number[i]=read.nextInt(); 

            if(number[i]%2==0){
                even.add(number[i]);  
                System.out.println("Even number is " + even);
            }
            else{
                odd.add(number[i]);
                System.out.println("Odd number is " + odd);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: int[]number=new int[10]; you are trying to read 10 numbers but passing only 4 at runtime.... isn't it strange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is working correctly, but your `println` statements should go after the `for` loop rather than inside of it. The output shows that it's printing the lists of odd and even numbers *as they're generated*, rather than after the whole input set has been processed.

```java
...
for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++){
    number[i]=read.nextInt();
    if(number[i]%2==0)
        even.add(number[i]);
    else
        odd.add(number[i]);
}
System.out.println("Even number is " + even);
System.out.println("Odd number is " + odd);
...
```

Comment: Strange: is there a conditional preventing the lines from being evaluated, or possibly the calls to `println` occur after `even` and `odd` have gone out of scope? Hard to diagnose without seeing your code. Does Abhishek's answer build and run on your system?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int[] number = new int[10];
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number :");

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            number[i] = read.nextInt();
            if (number[i] % 2 == 0) {
                even.add(number[i]);
            } else {
                odd.add(number[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even number is :");
        for (Integer e : even) {
            System.out.print(e + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\nOdd number is :");
        for (Integer o : odd) {
            System.out.print(o + " ");
        }
    }
```

You are printing inside the for loop where you are reading the user input. Print your data after you take the input as above.

Also note the difference in the way the output is formatted using **println** and **print** methods.